# .Net Core Entity Framework Core падает при попытке работы с MS SQL

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, model, entity-framework-core, codefirst

При попытке подключиться к SQL EXPRESS без созданной базы данных Entity Framework Core выбрасывает исключение неоднозначного содержания: толи пароль неверный толи базы данных не существует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Не удается открыть базу данных "...", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход. При входе в систему пользователя "..." произошла ошибка*

При этом если базу данных создать, то начнет ругаться на имя объекта, при этом как его не меняй - ничего не произойдет...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."SqlException: Недопустимое имя объекта "...".*

Следовал руководству с сайта Microsoft, вот ссылка https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть я что-то пропустил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework Core больше не создает таблицы и базу данных автоматически. Для этого нужно вызвать миграцию. Из кода C# сделать это можно так:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        if (Database.EnsureCreated()) Database.Migrate(); //Если базы данных не существует - создает миграцию
    }

    //public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RusEngDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

Comment: В VB.NET (не уверен насчет С#), поставщик SQL Compact, я просто вызываю Database.EnsureCreated(), этого достаточно - файл создается, если его нет. Версия EF Core 2.1